# Determine Integrability without use of Riemann Integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Determine the function is integrable or not on its interval of definition:

$f(x)=\begin{cases}0 \quad \textrm{if} \quad 0\le x\le1\\ x \quad \textrm{if} \quad 1\lt x \le2\end{cases}$

So in our class we cannot use Riemann Integral's to solve our problems, but we can use the Darboux Integral and it's related concepts. I want to say since the function is both discontinuous at 1 and not closed from 1 to 2, it is not integrable, but I'm not sure that's enough justification. We have also used the definitions of upper sum/integral and lower sum/integral:

$U(f,P) ; U(f) ; L(f,P) ; L(f)$

Can anyone provide some insight?

Also, would it make a difference if the function were:

$f(x)=\begin{cases}0 \quad \textrm{if} \quad 0\le x\lt1\\ x \quad \textrm{if} \quad 1\le x \le2\end{cases}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your possibilities for $f$ are integrable. Integration is not sensitive to whether the interval over which you integrate contains its endpoints. Integration also works for piecewise continuous functions like the functions $f$ you provided -- just integrate each piece separately and add the results up.

Comment: What conditions are required for a function to be non integrable? (besides the common example of x in reals and non reals)

Comment: It's usually easier to specify conditions under which a function will be integrable. For a very general type of integrable functions, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_integration

Comment: All right, thank you!